# Show and hide divs: SVG Into a html with several layers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I made an Svg and now I'm turning into a HTML. I'm using Jquery to show and hide divs. I have around 200 divs. Im using buttons, so, when I click on one div I have to show specific divs, but I need to hide all others. I think is not god to name one by one here. Can I show specific divs and hide all others??

I'm using this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#div1,#div3,#div2").click(function(){
   $('#div4,#div5,#div6,#div7').show(1000);
   // I need to hide all other divs, the 193 left...
   $('').hide(1000);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Give the divs you need to hide all at once a "class" instead of an "id".

https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#div1,#div3,#div2").click(function(){
   $('#div4,#div5,#div6,#div7').show(1000);
   // I need to hide all other divs, the 193 left...
   $('.generalClassName').hide(1000);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to what Hayden C posted would be to use a query selector and `.not()` to determine what divs you want to show vs hide. That is, if your divs `id`s all contain `div` (or something like it):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var toggleDivs = $('div[id*="div"]');

  $("#div1,#div2").click(function() {
    var targetDivs = $('#div3,#div4');
    var clickedDivs = $('#div1,#div2');
    targetDivs.show(1000);
    toggleDivs.not(targetDivs).not(clickedDivs).hide(1000);
  });

});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  border: dashed 1px steelblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="div1">1 - click me</div>
<div id="div2">2 - or me</div>
<div id="div3" style="display: none;">3</div>
<div id="div4" style="display: none;">4</div>
<div id="div5">5</div>
<div id="div6">6</div>
<div id="div7">7</div>
<div id="div8">8</div>
```

You could also accomplish the same thing using classes and `.not()`(as Hayden suggested):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var toggleDivs = $('.toggle');

    $("#div1,#div2").click(function () {
        var targetDivs = $('#div3,#div4');
        var clickedDivs = $('#div1,#div2');
        targetDivs.show(1000);
        toggleDivs.not(targetDivs).not(clickedDivs).hide(1000);
    });

});
```

```css
div {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    border: dashed 1px steelblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1" class="toggle">1 - click me</div>
<div id="div2" class="toggle">2 - or me</div>
<div id="div3" class="toggle" style="display: none;">3</div>
<div id="div4" class="toggle" style="display: none;">4</div>
<div id="div5" class="toggle">5</div>
<div id="div6" class="toggle">6</div>
<div id="div7" class="toggle">7</div>
<div id="div8" class="toggle">8</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right about not using `id` and naming them all in your jQuery.  Assuming that your divs are divided into consistent groups that all get shown and hidden together, the best approach would be to use classes.

Give each of the divs, that need to be shown together, the same `class`.  Divs can even be in more than one group.

```js
function showGroup(group)
{
    $("#hideables").children('div.'+group).show();
    $("#hideables").children('div').not('.'+group).hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="showGroup('dog')">Show dogs</button>
<button onclick="showGroup('cat')">Show cats</button>
<button onclick="showGroup('goat')">Show goats</button>

<div id="hideables">
    <div class="dog">dog</div>
    <div class="dog cat">dog cat</div>
    <div class="cat">cat</div>
    <div class="goat">goat</div>
    <div class="goat dog">goat dog</div>
</div>
```